# Normalize a vector: error

Tags: linear-algebra, vector, column

I have this simple example in which I am trying to write a column vector (ket vector) and then I want to normalize it. It seems that ther is something wrong, leading to an error message

"*The first argument is not a number or a vector,...* "

```
 myVec = {{1}, {2}};
Normalize[myVec]
```

How can one fix this. What is the best way of writing a ket vector and bra vector in *Mathematica*?

Edit: Related to some comments below, I want to added the following:

```
 mat1 = {{1}, {2}};
Dimensions[mat1](*(2,1)*)

    mat2 = {{1, 2}};
Dimensions[mat2](*(1,2)*)

    mat3 = {1, 2};
Dimensions[mat3](*(2)*)
```

Comment: `myVec = {1, 2}`

Comment: Would this be a row or a column vector?

Comment: No. `Normalize` accepts a vector, in Wolfram language, which means a `List` with an `ArrayDepth` 1; a row/column vector is represented by a matrix (a `List` of `List`s) with an `ArrayDepth` 2, unacceptable.

Comment: Tobias, there’s no practical distinction between row and column vectors in Mathematica. They are expressed the same way. You keep track of their “meaning” as you see fit.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica's vectors are always simple lists ([tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ScalarsVectorsAndMatrices.html)). In this sense there is no distinction between row vectors and column vectors, unlike Matlab etc.

A propos ket vs bra: if you define a state ket

```
p = {1, 2};
```

then the corresponding bra is simply

```
ps = Conjugate[p];
```

and is also a vector. The scalar product would be

```
ps.p
(* 5 *)
```

You could even define a scalar-product function

```
scp[a_?VectorQ, b_?VectorQ] /; Length[a] == Length[b] := Conjugate[a].b
```

and then calculate

```
scp[p,p]
(* 5 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make vectors a special case of matrices (this can be useful for some applications), you can normalize this way:

```
myVec/Norm[myVec]
(* {{1/Sqrt[5]}, {2/Sqrt[5]}} *)
```

Comment: It's a bit odd that *Mathematica* can handle `Norm[v]` when `v` is a "column vector", i.e., a list of 1-element lists, yet `Normalize` cannot. Is there some good reason that `Normalize` should not equally generalize like that?

Comment: I can only guess that whoever made this design decision judged that extending `Normalize` to matrices would cause more confusion than enlightenment.